# How to FILTER with LARGE condition on similar values?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table shown at [FILTER_LARGE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/183vruJsbaK6BJprY7gnZ7w9qWdJ_nPvc08f_SDkTg3k/edit?usp=sharing).
I would like to FILTER 3 highest values from column F by LARGE condition and 3 corresponding names from column E.
For some reason I would like to avoid using SORT function.

The issue is - how to retrieve the right values when some of cells in F have same numbers?

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are ties (same values ?) ?

Comment: I would like to show one over another then. I mean row by row.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean, but see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Query helps ?

```
=query(E1:F; "where F is not null order By F desc limit 3")
```

Alternatively (to include all ties), also try

```
=ArrayFormula(query(E1:F; "where F >= "&LARGE(unique(F:F); 3)&""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add Order By desc to @JPV answer:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(E1:F, "select E, F where F >= "&LARGE(unique(F:F), 3)&" order by F desc"))
```